# How to call onRowCommand event from custom control page(HWGridView.cs)

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, custom-controls

I wrote a code to create the GridView in Custom Control Page(example : HWGridView.cs).
Custom Control Page(HWGridView.cs), this page have all the event that can be used in GridView including OnRowCommand..etc.

Below the code, used in aspx page for creating GridView using Custom Control,

```
<grid:HWGridView runat="server" ID="grdView" AllowSorting="true"  OnRowCommand="grdView_RowDataBound" >
</grid:HWGridView>
```

How can i call OnRowCommand event from Custom Control Page(HWGridView.cs)

please refer the code from this link,
[Code](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/gridview/Custom-GridView-with-Paging-and-Filtering.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question.
You want to have an event handler method bound to the control?

If true, here it is

```
<grid:HWGridView runat="server" ID="grdView" AllowSorting="true"  OnRowCommand="grdView_RowCommand">
</grid:HWGridView>
```

What you had was a OnRowCommand event handler was bound to grdView_RowDataBound.
Remeber grdView_RowCommand needs to exist as well with correct arguments. Here's the signature:

```
public void grdView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
// your code here
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i wrote the code for rowCommand in Custom Control Page (HWGridView.cs). My question  is, how to call it from aspx page